# Which extension method is used when indexing into IEnumerable

Tags: vb.net, linq, .net-4.5

When indexing into an `IEnumerable`, I've noticed that using an index that is out of range will result in a default value being returned. I would have expected to receive an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. For example, this code results in `listItem` being 0. No exception is thrown.

```
Dim list As IEnumerable = New List(Of Integer)({1, 2, 3})
Dim listItem As Integer = CInt(list(-1))
```

If I cast as an `IList`, I get the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` as expected.

This code throws the exception.

```
Dim list As IList = New List(Of Integer)({1, 2, 3})
Dim listItem As Integer = CInt(list(-1))
```

The fact that I can index into `IEnumerable` is surprising in it of itself. I'm sure it's using `Linq` extensions, but I cannot figure out which is in use. The behavior seems to indicate the [ElementAtOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386(v=vs.100).aspx) method is being used, but I cannot find any documentation to support this.

What's going on here? Is there a good way to figure out which methods are actually in use?

Comment: I just found the more formal explanation here [Why can I access an item in KeyCollection/ValueCollection by index even if it doesn't implement IList(Of Key)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933428/why-can-i-access-an-item-in-keycollection-valuecollection-by-index-even-if-it-do)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  It's doing some compiler magic and converting that to a call to [Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386(v=vs.110).aspx) as you suspected.

I confirmed by compiling your code in VB.NET, and then using a decompiler tool to see the equivalent code in C#.

**EDIT**

I just found [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36933428/why-can-i-access-an-item-in-keycollection-valuecollection-by-index-even-if-it-do) that explains this behavior with references to the specification. Marked as a duplicate.